# Excess values of dimension are displayed in a browser

Tags: ssas, cube

I have a cube with the next structure: 
[image]

The problem is: 
When I'm browsing the cube using any attribute from the DimRetailStore dimension the browser displays values which don't belong to the FactStore measure. Excess values of the dimension disappear when I'm adding a metric from the FactStore. 
If I delete the FactRegion measure all data are displayed properly.

Is it possible to display only that data belong to the FactStore Measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution:** it was enough to move `FactRegion` under `FactStore` in the measures list.